# GWT ComboBox value change handler

Tags: java, gwt, combobox, gwt-ext

I have a `GWT-EXT ComboBox` having some 3-5 value in my project.
Can anyboy help me to find value change event(or selection event) ? 
Or any other way to get notified with GWT-EXT `ComboBox` state change.

Comment: There's no `ComboBox` in GWT, are you using a third-party widget library?

Answer (score 5):

If you are reffering to `Listbox`

**add[ChangeHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ChangeHandler.html)**

```
dropBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
      public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
        //do something
      }
    });
```

[Here is the live demo, source code.](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwListBox)

Comment: I had found this one but it's not working in GWT 2.4

Comment: Thanks buddy for your support, we've solved the problem with given answer

Comment: But seriously version is not at all problem here.You just don't what you are using. There is nothing like Combobox in gwt. There is only ListBox. You are using `GWT EXT` a third party gwt library.

Comment: @SURESHATTA Yes bro, lately i came to know about GWT-EXT in my project